# PHP json_encode() UTF-8 special characters fail

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

I am using html_entity_decode($string) to decode html special characters such as &auml=ä. I am then using json_encode() to create a json string that I use for an Android application. My problem is that i get an output of \u00e4 instead of 'ä'. I know that json_encode() only works with UTF-8 encoded strings, but when I run mb_detect_encding($myString) on my values it returns "UTF-8". It does't help to run ut8_encode() on the values. Here is my code:

```
$newsList = array();
while($row = $news->fetch_object()){
  $tmpNews = new News();
  $tmpNews->imgId = $row->image_id;
  $tmpNews->author = html_entity_decode($row->author);
  $tmpNews->subject = $row->subject;
  $tmpNews->msg = $row->msg;
  $tmpNews->newsmsg = $row->newsmsg;
  $tmpNews->date = $row->wdate;
  array_push($newsList, $tmpNews);
  $tmpNews = null;
}

$json = array();
foreach($newsList as $news){
  array_push($json, $news->getJson());
}
var_dump($json);
echo json_encode($json);
```

When i do the var_dump($json) my special characters shows as normal.

Comment: try json_encode($json,true);

Comment: Could you change the variable name "$json" to "$array", because it might confuse people when the names aren't reflecting the content. Then change the last line from "echo json_encode($json);" to "$json = json_encode($json);". Lastly var_dump both $array and $json and post the output here.. :)

Comment: json_encode($json,true); didn't help. Can add that adding the flag JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE helps and fixes the problem. But the server I am using is running php 5.3.3 and therefore I can't use that flag.